# A brand new Samsung laptop with extremely slow internet connection

Tags: networking, router, performance, internet, connection

I just got a new Samsung laptop with windows 8, and the internet is extremely slow, altough every other computer in the house works fine.

My internet connection is supposed to be 100mbps, but in most computers in the house it's around 85. On this one it's less then 1!

Some info:

1. Tried wireless and with a wire directly to the router, problem sticks.
2. The DNS, IP Address and Getaway are fine.
3. The computer is brand new, nothing downloaded so it's not a malware or virus.
4. It's brand new so no programs stealing bandwidth.

Any ideas?

Comment: How are you measuring the connection speed on this laptop?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you downgrade to Windows 7, and do a CLEAN install meaning delete every single file so it's like new... again. If it's still slow, then it's a hardware issue, and I would suggest you bring your laptop back to the store and ask for a replacement.

My second solution is to plug in the Ethernet cord right in your laptop, and if the speed is the same, than take it back to the store, if the speed is fast like your other computers then update your wireless drivers.

So,

- Reinstall Windows
- Update Drivers
- Take the laptop back to the store and ask for a replacement and describe your issue

Comment: He paid for Win8 and perhaps is in no mood to downgrade. Why not reset Win8 itself?

Comment: Well, yeah thats true.